# Runtime error: Unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm new to using a mac and iOS development. Today I followed [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5138/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-1) on to a how to bind data to a table view by making use of Prototype cells and the Story Board. I've got up to the part of the tutorial where I should be able to run the app so the bound data shows up in the UITableView like this:

[image]

My app compiles fine, but as soon as it starts running it hits a runtime error:

```
[ViewController viewControllers]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

I have tried going through the tutorial several times now. I've followed the tutorial exactly as it says and have even created 3 different projects from scratch to make sure that nothing is going wrong. Can anybody help me fix the error? I've spent hours trying to work out what's going wrong, and I don't want to give up now as iOS development seems so exciting compared to other platforms!

Comment: Set an [exception breakpoint](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_an_exception_breakpoint.html) and the debugger will stop on the exception.

Comment: I tried adding breakpoints too. I have a feeling that the '@synthesize players;' code is causing the error. I'm putting this code after '@implementation PlayersViewController' within my playersViewController.m file. Does anyone know if this is where it should be? I haven't come across synthesize yet, so I'll have to do some further reading and report back.

Comment: You do not need `@synthesize` directive anymore. It is from earlier days when compiler needed that. You may leave it there it won't hurt. What you need is only a property definition `@property...`

Comment: I'd be greatly surprised if it has anything to do with synthesize.  Look at any place where you're using the "viewControllers" method/property.

Answer (score 0):

Unrecognized selector means that there is an undefined method being called.

One thing to do is to see if there are any compiler warnings. Does it give you any? Have a look, it may give you a clue what is undefined.

The tutorial refers to ViewController class. It looks like that this class is used briefly at the start of the tutorial but then it is replaced with another class. You may remove this class later on altogether. Check if you wire tab bar controller properly. have you set it to be "an entry point"?

Check the storyboard. Where does an incoming arrow point to? Compare two images below. First has the entry arrow pointing to ViewController (my guess), second - the arrow point to Tab Bar Controller

[image: image1]

---

[image: later image].

Comment: Actually, the message is quite specific.  It states that somewhere the method "viewControllers" was called on an object of class "ViewController", and that class does not support the named method.  (Hint: Look at any place where you use the method "viewControllers".)

Comment: No warnings, or usages of a viewControllers method in any of my source files. Hmm this is so odd :/

Comment: According to the tutorial `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` should call viewControllers methos.

Answer (score 0):

At some point (without the code is hard to tell where) you are getting a reference to a `ViewController`, treating it as a `UITabBarViewController`.

`viewControllers` is a method of `UITabBarViewController` but you are invoking it on a `ViewController`.

You probably have something like

```
UITabBarViewController *tabBarVC = (UITabBarViewController *)[something aMethod];
tabBarVC.viewControllers...
```

So it compiles fine, but it rightfully crashes at runtime.

Comment: No, he's invoking it on ViewController -- without the "UI".  But it very likely extends UIViewController.